# JavaMail Maven Error

Tags: maven, email, jakarta-mail, pom.xml

I used JavaMail with my plugin to send an email and that that worked fine a couple of months ago. I now came back to update my plugin and do some more bug testing and for some reason when I try and send an email from the plugin the following error is thrown:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.mail.util.MailLogger
```

My pom.xml current looks like this, I am using both the activation jar and JavaMail:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spigot-repo</id>
        <url>https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <!--Spigot API-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.spigotmc</groupId>
        <artifactId>spigot-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.12.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!--Bukkit API-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bukkit</groupId>
        <artifactId>bukkit</artifactId>
        <version>1.12.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!--Activation-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--Java Mail-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--Google Authentication-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.warrenstrange</groupId>
        <artifactId>googleauth</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an error in the POM of your dependency. When looking at `javax.mail.Session.java:198` from Maven artifact `javax.mail:javax.mail-api:1.6.0`, it does indeed have a compile-time dependency (and should have been declared in its POM) to `com.sun.mail.util.MailLogger`.

**javax.mail.Session.java:**

```
57    import com.sun.mail.util.MailLogger;
...
190   public final Session {
191
192      private final Properties props;
193      private final Authenticator authenticator;
194      private final Hashtable<URLName, PasswordAuthentication> authTable
195         = new Hashtable<>();
196      private boolean debug = false;
197      private PrintStream out;           // debug output stream
198      private MailLogger logger;
...
```

Whether this error depends on the human factor or not I'll leave it up you to decide.

Since you are not in control of this artifact, I suggest you just *change* your dependency to `javax.mail:javax.mail-api:1.6.0` to the following to your POM:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

This dependency contains the exact same classes (byte-for-byte) as `javax.mail:javax.mail-api:1.6.0` does, but with the addition of the `com.sun.mail.*` stuff that the mail API needs:

**EDIT**

```
$ jar tvf com/sun/mail/javax.mail/1.6.0/javax.mail-1.6.0.jar
...[lines omitted]...
  7688 Mon Jul 17 12:53:30 CEST 2017 com/sun/mail/util/MailLogger.class
```

This jar has the following hash:

```
$ sha1sum com/sun/mail/javax.mail/1.6.0/javax.mail-1.6.0.jar
a055c648842c4954c1f7db7254f45d9ad565e278
```

Comment: Thank you for replying, I changed it to "com.sun.mail", "javax.mail", "1.6.0" but it's still throwing off the same error it just can't find that class..

Comment: Something is hiding that class. Are you using any sealed jars or Java 9?

Comment: As described on the [JavaMail project page](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/#Download_JavaMail_Release), the javax.mail-api artifact is only intended for compiling against; it's not suitable for runtime.  The com.sun.mail:javax.mail artifact is the one you want.  If you're still getting the same error, then you've done something else wrong.

Comment: I am not sure, It used to work perfectly fine and just a couple months later it stopped. It seems to be happening to different packages I try. I am not sure if why Maven is being so weird. I am currently running Java 10

Comment: I don’t think Maven is necessarily the culprit here. Are you able to run your code with the JVM flag `-verbose:class` to find out where your JavaMail classes get loaded from? Could it be that the `com.sun.mail.util` package is a _split package_ as defined by JPMS? Did it work before with JRE 8 or below?